# PHP - MYSQL: How to retrieve column information using Alias

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a PHP system for email marketing campaigns. I need to create a page showing all the titles that  the user clicked based on his/her e-mail address.

The table **wysylki_reakcje** stores the email address of the client, the unique ID of the email campaign (*id_wysylki*), and the ID of the link (*id_link*).

http://s28.postimg.org/a2vx45uj1/table_wysylki_reakcje.jpg

A 2nd table called **wysylki_linki** stores the information I need to retrieve from the column *nazwa_linku*.

http://s17.postimg.org/wa655h3gv/table_wysylki_linki.jpg

The relation of both tables are the columns *id_wysylki* and *id_link*

My code so far ( my query is currently not working properly)

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id_link,id_wysylki,email,data_godz,nazwa_linku 
FROM wysylki_reakcje AS T1, wysylki_linki AS T3  
WHERE (T1.id_link=T3.nazwa_linku)  
AND email='client_email@company.com'" ;

if ($res = $mysqli->query($sql2)) {
    echo "<table\n";    
    echo "<tbody>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
        printf("<td>%s</td>", $row['nazwa_linku']);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</tbody>\n";
echo "<table>\n";
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query?  If the wrong data shows up, a bit of sample data from both tables will help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: the query is wrong - no join in there !

Comment: i am having trouble understanding your table definition !

Comment: When I run the query I only get blank screen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query should look something like this :

```
SELECT 
T1.id_link,
T1.id_wysylki,
T1.email,
T1.data_godz,
T3.nazwa_linku FROM wysylki_reakcje AS T1
   inner join wysylki_linki AS T3 
   on T1.id_wysylki = T3.id_wysylki  
WHERE T1.id_link=T3.nazwa_linku
   AND T3.email='client_email@company.com';
```

But you need to have some keys on your **wysylki_linki.id_wysylki** column referencing the **wysylki_reakcje.id_wysylki**  !
 **An syntax example of join :**

```
SELECT tab1.col1, tab2.col1
FROM `tab1`
INNER JOIN `tab2` on tab1.col1 = tab2.col2;
```

One more thing - check this link for more on  joins http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/